# An answer disappeared?

Tags: support, deleted-answers

I am a 10k+ user so I should be able to see deleted answers.

I was answering [Joda-Time: Strange behavior for leap year in Period calculation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39629657/joda-time-strange-behavior-for-leap-year-in-period-calculation). When I started entering my answer there were already two answers.  When I submitted my answer, one of those other answers had completely disappeared.

I presume it was deleted by the owner.  How does an answer disappear completely such that it is not visible to a 10k+ user?

Comment: The only times I've seen this are when the database was restored from a previous point in time or answers were *moved* to another question. Both are extremely rare; you sure it wasn't a comment?

Comment: No, it was definitely an answer. I seem to recall something about a short grace period during which answers can be edited by the owner without the edits showing up in the history.  Does this apply to deletes as well?

Comment: @Jim Garrison: No.

Comment: @Shog9: Shouldn't a move like that leave some kind of trace?

Comment: Yes, @cerbrus - I don't think that happened here.

Comment: [Employees can move answers around](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/280683/editing-a-question-from-the-close-queue-and-not-editing-anything-marks-the-revie/280726#comment911657_280726) - I'm not sure what kind of trace it leaves, though.

Comment: ... which Shog just answered over an hour before.

Comment: #10kproblems :P